# Why is this smooth scroll script only working for one button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to add smooth scrolling to my website for safari and came across [this](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) solution which works great. But adding it to my website only worked for one button in the header. It would probably work if you'd copy paste the script and use a different class for each button but is there a way to make one script work for alle the buttons?

My code:

```js
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {

      // scroll into view
      document.querySelector('.scrollwrap').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('.wrapper').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      });
      });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sample {
  margin-top: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.4/dist/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="assets/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
  </head>

  <body>
<ul>
          <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" data-number="1" class="activenav navb scrollwrap">link1</button></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" data-number="2" class="navb scrollwrap">link2</button></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" data-number="3" class="navb scrollwrap">link3</button></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" data-number="4" class="navb scrollwrap">link4</button></li>
        </ul>
 
  
  <section class="sample wrapper">
      <article class="scrollable-element-to-top">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
      </article>
      </section>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.querySelector()` returns the first element. `.querySelectorAll` returns an array, which you can loop through.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // scroll into view
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollwrap');
  for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {

    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.querySelector('.wrapper').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sample {
  margin-top: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.4/dist/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="assets/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" data-number="1" class="activenav navb scrollwrap">link1</button></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" data-number="2" class="navb scrollwrap">link2</button></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" data-number="3" class="navb scrollwrap">link3</button></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><button type="button" data-number="4" class="navb scrollwrap">link4</button></li>
  </ul>


  <section class="sample wrapper">
    <article class="scrollable-element-to-top">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this works great, thanks for that. Is it possible to somehow implement something like `scroll-margin-top: 130px;` to the code? Something like an offset?